# Get project path from POCO migration Seed()

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, poco

I'm trying to get the executable path within the Seed() thread.  However I'm not getting the values I want. My aim is to enumerate files within the executable path, and work with those;

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DBContext context)
    {
        // get list of files
        var sqlfileList = Directory.GetFiles(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    }
}
```

Output from the Package Manager Console;

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm expecting;

```
C:\Development\My.Domain
```

Comment: what directorys do you expect

Comment: Note, that executable path and current directory are very different things.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`

Note that it will return the path of your process exe.

You'll have to use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)` to get the path of the directory containing your process exe.

For MSDN :

`GetCallingAssembly` => The assembly of the method that invoked the currently executing method.
`GetExecutingAssembly` => The assembly that contains the code that is currently executing.
`GetEntryAssembly` => The assembly that is the process executable.

Comment: Sorry none of those work from within Seed(), GetEntryAssembly() throws a null reference exception.

Comment: I think this is because I'm calling it from an internal sealed class